# Trigger function that reorders a unique column not applied

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using Postgres 9.5, it seems I am missing something very easy but I can't apply my trigger function.

I have a table `list_items` that contains lists and and corresponding items with their positions, i.e.:

```
-------------------------
id | list | item | pos (for position) 
--------------------------
--------------------------
```

`list` and `item` are just foreign keys to the ids corresponding to their own tables, `id` is just a serial primary key.

the position `pos` is unique for an item corresponding to some list (i.e. UNIQUE(list, item, pos))

The user may change or delete the position for some item in a list, I need to have a trigger that reorders the positions of all other affected items in case of an UPDATE or DELETE.

For example, if a list L has 6 items having `pos` from 1 to 6, If I delete  item whose `pos` = 3, I need to reorder 'pos' for items in L from 4 - 6 to become 3 - 5, Also if I change the `pos` for exmaple from 5 to 3 using UPDATE, I need to reorder items 3, 4 to become 4, 5.

Here are my Trigger functions

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION reorder_delete() RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE rw RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR rw IN SELECT * FROM list_items WHERE list = OLD.list AND pos > OLD.pos
    LOOP
        UPDATE list_items SET pos = rw.pos - 1 WHERE id = rw.id;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER do_reorder_delete
    AFTER DELETE ON list_items
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE reorder_delete();


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION reorder_update() RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE rw RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR rw IN SELECT * FROM list_items WHERE list = NEW.list AND pos >= NEW.pos ORDER BY pos DESC
    LOOP
        UPDATE list_items SET pos = rw.pos + 1 WHERE id = rw.id;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER do_reorder_update
    BEFORE UPDATE ON list_items
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE reorder_update();
```

The problem is whenever I do UPDATE or DELETE operation, nothing happens a t all! (for DELETE, the designated row is deleted but the trigger is not applied)

Comment: The `reorder_update()` should use `return new;` **not** `RETURN NULL;` (return `null` makes the trigger ignore the update)

Comment: You are also dropping the update trigger at the end of the script.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks, I did try `RETURN NEW;` but it gives me something like an overflow or infinite loop execution

Comment: Do you need to update the row you are on before going through the loop again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two triggers. The first runs a function that updates some rows. The second also runs a function that updates some rows.

Whenever rows are updated the second function will be run.

This includes when rows are updated by *either* trigger.

Re-evaluate your functions in this light and see if this matches what you are seeing.

Also, you may find RAISE NOTICE useful to show what each function is doing.

Comment: Thanks, it seems this is why I got infinite loop, the update inside the function will invoke endlessly the trigger function which contains another update. I will abandon this path and update them one by one until I find a more performant solution. Thanks again!